# Calculated Query Field ignoring some results

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a calculated field in a query that takes our total revenue per customer and subtracts out total costs per customer to get our margins with that customer.  The formula works fine as long as the customer has a cost value but if the customer has no cost, the formula is ignoring that revenues exists and is excluding that customer from the total and the query does not include them in the returned result.  Is there a way to fix the formula to include these customers with no costs but still generate revenue?

```sql
SELECT [Company Information].[Company Name], ([2 YTD - Customer 
Revenues].SumOfSumOfCharge-[2 YTD - Customer Costs].[SumOfTotal Cost]) 
AS [Customer Margin]
```

Comment: Yes, that solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a query run from within an Access session, you can use `Nz` to have Access substitute 0 for Null when it computes the difference ...

```sql
Nz([2 YTD - Customer Costs].[SumOfTotal Cost], 0)
```

Alternatively you could use an `IIf` expression to accomplish the same thing ...

```sql
IIf([2 YTD - Customer Costs].[SumOfTotal Cost] Is Null, 0, [2 YTD - Customer Costs].[SumOfTotal Cost])
```

Support for `IIf` is built into the db engine, so it is available for any Access query.  `Nz` is an external (VBA) function which the db engine can use within an Access session.  So the `IIf` approach should theoretically be faster, but may not be *noticeably* faster in practice.

Comment: I had attempted the `IIF` Approach however kept running into error messages regarding my groupings and not containing various things as aggregate functions so I switched to the `Nz` method.  Thanks for your help.